# How to get friends name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using this code:

```
   function login() {

       FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
               console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');

               FB.api('/me/friends', {
                   fields: 'id,name'
               }, function(response) {
                   for (element in response) {
                       console.log(element.name);
                   }
               });


           } else {
               console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
       }, {
           'scope': 'user_friends'
       });
   }
```

but I get this response in the console:

```
Welcome! Fetching your information.... 
2 undefined
```

Why ?

EDIT:

I have just edited the code above:

```
   function login() {

       FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
               console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');

               FB.api('/me/friends', {
                   fields: 'id,name'
               }, function(response) {
                   console.log(response.summary);
                   console.log(response);
                   for (element in response.data) {
                       console.log(element.id);
                   }
               });


           } else {
               console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
       }, {
           'scope': 'user_friends'
       });
   }
```

but now I get this response:

```
Welcome! Fetching your information.... 
Object {total_count: 58}
Object {data: Array[0], summary: Object}
```

Comment: @WizKid just edited the question with the response :)

Comment: the response is correct, none of your friends authorized your app yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get all friends anymore. You can only get friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too.

This would be the correct code:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', {
   fields: 'id,name'
}, function(response) {
   for (element in response.data) {
       console.log(element.name);
   }
});
```

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: is there any way to get the friends's id ?

Comment: only if that friend authorized your app, as you can read in my answer. read the accepted answer of the link in my answer too.